# Custom extension extra step in Onepage checkout not updating progress Magento 1.9.1

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme, onestepcheckout

I have created a module for the Onepage checkout that overrides and adds a custom step. The progress for this step is shown until I submit the information and then the progress block disappears entirely from the page. I'm using a custom **rwd** theme and followed mostly this tutorial: http://www.boolfly.com/add-custom-fields-to-order-magento-part-1/ I've traced it down to where my custom template is not able to get the checkout session:

```
<?php if($this->getCheckout()->getStepData('extra_fields', 'complete')): ?>
<dt class="complete">
    <?php echo $this->__('Person Placing Order') ?> 
    <span class="separator">|</span> 
    <a href="#deliverydate" onclick="checkout.accordion.openSection('opc-extra_fields'); return false;"><?php echo $this->__('Change') ?></a>
</dt>
<dd class="complete">
    <div>
        <?php echo $this->__('Person Placing Order: ');?>
    </div>
    <p class="printout"><?php echo $this->getCheckout()->getData('ef_first_name').' '.$this->getCheckout()->getData('ef_last_name') ?></p>
</dd>
<?php else: ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('Person Placing Order') ?>
    </dt>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I set the *'extra_fields'* value as complete in the method:

```
 public function saveExtraFieldsAction()
{
    if($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('extra', array());
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveExtraFields($data);
        Mage::log($result);
        if(!isset($result['error'])) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'checkout_controller_onepage_save_extrafields_method',
                array(
                    'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                    'quote'   => $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()));
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'payment-method',
                'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
            );
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

The layout file that overrides the checkout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>extrafields/checkout/onepage.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="extrafields_checkout/onepage_extrafields" name="extra_fields" as="extra_fields" 
                        template="extrafields/checkout/onepage/extrafields.phtml"/>
            </reference>
            <reference name="checkout.progress" before="-">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="fields.progress" as="fields.progress" template="extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress/fields.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </checkout_onepage_index>
        <checkout_onepage_progress>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="fields.progress" template="extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress/fields.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="billing.progress" template="extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </checkout_onepage_progress>
        <checkout_onepage_progress_billing>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <template>extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </checkout_onepage_progress_billing>
        <checkout_onepage_progress_extra_fields>
            <remove name="right"/>
            <remove name="left"/>

            <block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="root" output="toHtml" template="extrafields/checkout/onepage/progress/fields.phtml">
                <action method="setInfoTemplate"><method></method><template></template></action>
            </block>
        </checkout_onepage_progress_extra_fields>
    </layout>
```

Any ideas why the template file is not able to access the checkout session?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the overridden OnePage Model Type saveShippingMethod:

```
    public function saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
{
    if (empty($shippingMethod)) {
        return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
    }
    $rate = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod);
    if (!$rate) {
        return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
    }
    $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
        ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);

    $this->getCheckout()
        ->setStepData('shipping_method', 'allow', true)
        ->setStepData('shipping_method', 'complete', true)
        ->setStepData('extra_fields', 'allow', true);
    return array();
}
```

I originally did not have the `->setStepData('shipping_method', 'allow', true)` in there which was causing the error. Hope this helps someone!